# JIRA GreenHopper Plugins

Tags: plugins, jira, jira-agile

Are there any GreenHopper plugins out there enhancing the Agile capabilities of JIRA? I'm specifically looking for a better solution to the current "Sprint" field in GreenHopper.

Comment: The current GreenHopper Sprint field does not play well with the JIRA task boards, etc. I have seen a GreenHopper extension a while back that does a neater integration. But, unfortunately I can't remember the name of this plugin.

Comment: is the "Sprint" field a new feature? I don't see it in my instance. I just use versions for sprints. Works OK for my setting. So again: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

The new GreenHopper [Rapid Board](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+the+Rapid+Board) feature is a large step forward (IMHO) for the sprint planning and sprint management -- and this from someone who used to be 30-50% frustrated with the agile features of Jira/GH.  You do need to upgrade your Jira to 5.x and then use the "Labs" features to enable the latest Greenhopper, and you need to re-index your Jira issue database.

> The Rapid Board is a fresh start for GreenHopper. We are building it to take advantage of the latest in web technology and provide you, the customer, with an awesome experience for planning, tracking and reporting on the progress of your agile projects and teams.

The Greenhopper team within Atlassian has been working towards their new [road map for Greenhopper](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/The+Future+of+GreenHopper) very quickly and our team has been very impressed with the progress.  One of our favorite improvements (there are many) is the ability to add stories/tasks from multiple projects to your current sprint.

> One thing is absolutely clear: your agile project does not necessarily map to a single JIRA Project. For that reason we have addressed the most common feature request — [GHS-1800](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-1800), support for more than one JIRA project in GreenHopper. Not being folks to sit still, we are taking this opportunity to introduce a new user experience with fewer page reloads and more useful URLs —  users will be able to have a URL for the displayed page ([GHS-990](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-990)).

***It's as if they have actually listened to their customers in developing the latest GH.***

The new planning board also has been a big timesaver - I would say that our sprint planning time has been reduced by about half.